# How to run only N thread at time of curl in Bash?

Tags: objective-c, c, multithreading, bash, curl

I am writing a console program in Objective-C. It create 10k URLs to download. When I create a URL, I can easily download it with:

```
system("curl --url 'URL' --output 'PATH'");
```

Downloading one by one is slow but work. I tried to use thread but it is difficult to implement. So, I create this dirty algorithm:

```
for(x in 1 to N) write 'finish' in file name_x.txt
while(there is URL) {
    THREAD=-1;
    for(x in 1 to N){
        check file name_x.txt exist and if I can delete it;  
        if (true) delete file and set THREAD=x
     }
     if(THREAD!=-1) {
         download(URL, THREAD)
     } else {
         wait(1) // and will try again
    }
}

function download(URL, THREAD) {
     system("curl --url '%s' -o 'myfile.html' && echo 'finish' >  name_%i.txt &", URL, THREAD);
}
```

And... it almost work perfectly. I know it is not the best strategy, but increase the speed to download insanely more.

But... My log show a lot of error messages. It download 70% of all page I want. Then I just download the rest in only one thread.

The log show errors in this way:

```
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
system return = 32768  // or 0x8000
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
system return = 32768
....
```

And

```
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
....
system return = -1   // or 0xFFFF
system return = -1
....
```

What this mean? My system (Mac OS X 10.7.5) can't run the number of jobs I set (45)? But I decrease and see the same error..

How can I solve it, or how can I download 10k pages downloading N pages at time?

Comment: Maybe I duplicate this question with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318165/how-to-download-n-urls-at-time-with-curl-programmatically ;D

Comment: I am having new ideas. I can write N bash script and open all of then in background at same time. This will create the threads in a lazy way and work bether.